# Notepad++ Regex replace containing certain string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm having a few problems with Notepad++ and Regexes. How would I be able to delete each 'thing' containing the term "deletethisone"?

```nolang
thing
beforestuff deletethisone
endthing

thing
beforestuff notthisone
endthing

thing
beforestuff deletethisone
endthing

thing
beforestuff notthisone
endthing
```

I've got the ". matches newline" enabled, by the way.

If anyone could help with this then that'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
thing(?=(?:(?!thing|endthing).)*?deletethisone).*?endthing
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/vR4fY4/18

Answer (score 0):

```
((?<=\n)|^)[^\n]+?\n[^\n]+?deletethisone\n[^\n]+?(?=\n|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

A short regex

Find what: `(.*\n.*delete.*\n.*)`
Replace with: `nothing`